# Múltiples párrafos dentro de un array js

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Necesito introducir varias lineas dentro de un array en js mas o menos como muestro abajo, pero no se como se puede hacer

```js
properties: {
  title: '<?php echo $row["ROTULO"] ?>',
  description: '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_A"] ?></p>'
             . '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_B"] ?></p>'
             . '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_C"] ?></p>'
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con [*backticks*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `Javascript` podes contatenar cadenas usando:

### Opción 1: el operador `+`

**Ejemplo:**

```
properties: {
  title: '<?php echo $row["ROTULO"] ?>',
  description: '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_A"] ?></p>' +
             '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_B"] ?></p>' +
             '<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_C"] ?></p>'
}
```

Un dato importante a tener en cuenta es que el operador `+` debe estar al final de la línea **siempre**

---

### Opción 2: [Plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

**Ejemplo:**

```
properties: {
  title: '<?php echo $row["ROTULO"] ?>',
  description: `<p><?php echo $row["PRICE_A"] ?></p>
             <p><?php echo $row["PRICE_B"] ?></p>
             <p><?php echo $row["PRICE_C"] ?></p>`
}
```